# internet-explorer-8 tabs

Tags: internet-explorer-8

I have created an application in  asp.net

If I have opened the same application in 2 tabs internet-explorer-8 
 do they share same session?
 what is the case if it is not internet-explorer-8?

I mean browsers like chrome or mozilla

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they share the same session. IE8, IE9, Firefox and Chrome.

Firefox and Chrome have new modes (Private Browsing and Incognito) which allow to use new windows with different sessions.

Comment: IE9 has it too - InPrivate Browsing.